# Pandas MultiIndex dataframe to nested json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index, nested-json

I have the following pandas multi-index dataframe and I would like it to become a nested json object.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'store_id' : ['1', '1','1','2','2'],
        'item_name' : ['apples', 'oranges', 'pears', 'persimmons', 'bananas'],
        '2022-01-01': [2.33, 1.99, 2.33, 2.33, 4.21],
        '2022-01-02': [2.38, 1.96, 2.38, 2.37, 4.34],
        '2022-01-03': [2.45, 1.78, 2.45, 2.45, 4.13]}
        
df = pd.DataFrame(data).groupby(['store_id', 'item_name']).first()

print(df)
```

Output:

```
# The indices are store_id and item_name.

store_id    item_name    2022-01-01 2022-01-02  2022-01-03          
       1       apples       2.33          2.38        2.45
              oranges       1.99          1.96        1.78
                pears       2.33          2.38        2.45
       2      bananas       4.21          4.34        4.13
           persimmons       2.33          2.37        2.45
```

I would like it to become a json object with nested levels that looks like this:

```
{
  1: {
    apples: [
      { date: "2022-01-01", price: 2.33 },
      { date: "2022-01-02", price: 2.38 },
      { date: "2022-01-03", price: 2.45 },
    ],
    oranges: [
      { date: "2022-01-01", price: 1.99 },
      { date: "2022-01-02", price: 1.96 },
      { date: "2022-01-03", price: 1.78 },
    ],
    pears: [
      { date: "2022-01-01", price: 2.33 },
      { date: "2022-01-02", price: 2.38 },
      { date: "2022-01-03", price: 2.45 },
    ],
  },

  2: {
    persimmons: [
      { date: "2022-01-01", price: 2.33 },
      { date: "2022-01-02", price: 2.37 },
      { date: "2022-01-03", price: 2.45 },
    ],
    bananas: [
      { date: "2022-01-01", price: 4.21 },
      { date: "2022-01-02", price: 4.34 },
      { date: "2022-01-03", price: 4.13 },
    ],
  },
}
```

I've tried every permutation of pandas's `to_json` but nothing gives me the nesting I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension for add custom format of inner dicts:

```
import json

d = {level: {k1: [{'date': k, 'price': v} 
             for k, v in v1.items()] 
             for k1, v1 in df.xs(level).T.items()}
             for level in df.index.levels[0]}


j = json.dumps(d)
print (j)
```

---

```
    '1': {
        'apples': [{
            'date': '2022-01-01',
            'price': 2.33
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-02',
            'price': 2.38
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-03',
            'price': 2.45
        }],
        'oranges': [{
            'date': '2022-01-01',
            'price': 1.99
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-02',
            'price': 1.96
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-03',
            'price': 1.78
        }],
        'pears': [{
            'date': '2022-01-01',
            'price': 2.33
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-02',
            'price': 2.38
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-03',
            'price': 2.45
        }]
    },
    '2': {
        'bananas': [{
            'date': '2022-01-01',
            'price': 4.21
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-02',
            'price': 4.34
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-03',
            'price': 4.13
        }],
        'persimmons': [{
            'date': '2022-01-01',
            'price': 2.33
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-02',
            'price': 2.37
        }, {
            'date': '2022-01-03',
            'price': 2.45
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm and is also very quick on larger datasets. Thanks @jezrael